# GRASS GIS gui or shell?

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.2

I am shifting from QGIS to GRASS GIS. I believe GRASS GIS enables better automatization and QGIS basically uses a bunch of GRASS GIS functions anyway.

However, the change is not as smooth as I thought it would. Knowing that I am already familiar with shell scripting, what would be, in your opinion, the best way to start using GRASS, working with the GRASS GIS GUI or directly with the GRASS shell?

Comment: Wrong question format (opinion-based answer) for this site. But if you want to automate, learn bash+CLI, skip the GUI. Totally unnecessary. If it gets complicated, then you need to go to Python interface. QGIS still pretty good for visualization (if you don't need to automate that part).